Como guardar un reporte en excel desde jasperreport
Tengo un reporte de jasperreport que necesito exportarlo a excel, pero cuando le doy a guardar en el visor del reporte, me da el siguiente mensaje:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/util/HSSFColor$WHITE
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.(JRXlsExporter.java:169)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.save(JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.java:118)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewer.java:1233)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$3.actionPerformed(JRViewer.java:763)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$WHITE
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 41 more

Y me pasa lo mismo si lo intento desde el código de la siguiente manera:
private void mostrarReporte()
{
    try
    {
        String path = "H:/sistemas/Ejecutable Avances/Rsys/Reportes Produccion/Produccion_Suela/Vale_Entrada/Vale.jasper";
        
        JasperReport jsReporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
        
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("Fecha_1", Fecha1);
        param.put("Fecha_2", Fecha2);
        param.put("Turno", turno);
        
        JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jsReporte, param, c);
        
        JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("Vale.xlsx"));
        exporter.exportReport();
        
        frm.maximizarReporte(jPrint, "TOP-SUELAS");
    }
    catch(JRException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                                      "No se pudo cargar el reporte seleccionado.\n" + ex.getMessage(),
                                      "TOP-SUELAS", 
                                      JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

También cheque en internet, y solo encontré que era problema de las librería poi, pero ya le puse la version 5.2.5 y me sigue generando el mismo error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/util/HSSFColor$WHITE, indica que tu aplicación no puede encontrar la clase HSSFColor$WHITE que forma parte de la biblioteca Apache POI
Asegúrate de que Apache POI está incluido en tu proyecto
Clean del proyecto y revisa que te la reconozca en el classpath
no se si estas en mvn revisa las dependencias que te las este cogiendo bien
dependency:tree
y su compatibilidad
